# Proof of a equation about fibre of flat morphism

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let ($A,m,k$) and ($B,n,k'$) be noetherian local rings, and let $A\to B$ be a local homomorphsim. Let $M$ be a finite $A$-module and $N$ be a finite $B$-module which is $A$-flat. Then

depth$_B(M\otimes_A N)$=depth$_A M$ + depth$_{B}(N\otimes k)$

In the proof, the case depth$M>0$, while depth$_B(N\otimes k)=0$ was left as an exercise, which I failed to proof. Since $N$ is flat, a free resolution of $M$ induces a free resoluton of $M\otimes N$. So we only need to proof that $Ext^i_A(k,M)=0$ means $Ext^i_B(k',M\otimes N)=0$. Also, we know that depth$_B(N\otimes k)=0$ means $n\in Ass_B(N\otimes k)$. But how does it help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Proposition 1.2.16  and Lemma 1.2.17 in Bruns-Herzog provides a complete proof of this result.

Comment: Can you give me a link?

Comment: [Page 13 and 14](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&lpg=PR3&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false).